# Pandas dataframe not updating during iteration (itertuples), but works independently outside of function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Earlier I create a dataframe for every balance reading that contains a 0 on a particular day. But when it comes time to run the while loop, the if statement   does not ever find a nonzero balance reading, even when it does exist.

I independently ran the code for one particular account and it passed through all my code and found the previous balance and replaced it, but I had to do it sequentially, not all in one function. My guess is that itertuples is the source of this problem.

```
# df looks like this with amount_y being the balance (ignore amount_x for now, it represents transaction amount/day/account):

# accrual_date | financial_account_id | amount_x | amount_y

def updateBalance(df):
    index = 0
    for row in df.itertuples():
        old_balance = 0
        index_when_condition_met = 0

        if df.loc[index,'amount_y'] == 0:
            financial_account_id_search = df.loc[index,'financial_account_id']
            accrual_date_search = df.loc[index,'accrual_date']
            ordered = df[df['financial_account_id'].str.match(financial_account_id_search)].sort_values(by='accrual_date').reset_index(drop=True)

            for row2 in ordered.itertuples():

                index_when_condition_met = ordered[(ordered['accrual_date'].str.match(accrual_date_search)) & (ordered['amount_y'] == 0)].index.values[0] #takes first balance reading if more than one balance reading of 0 took place on same day


                while index_when_condition_met > 0:

                    if ordered.loc[index_when_condition_met - 1,'amount_y'] != 0: # previous balance is not 0,

                        old_balance = ordered.loc[index_when_condition_met - 1,'amount_y']
                        break
                    else: # previous balance is 0, need to check earlier entries
                        index_when_condition_met = index_when_condition_met - 1

                if index_when_condition_met == 0:
                    old_balance = 0
                    df.at[index,"amount_y"] = old_balance # might be redundant

                else:
                    df.at[index,"amount_y"] = old_balance

        index = index + 1                                                                        
    return df
updateBalance(df)
```

The new resulting dataframe for e should have replaced all 0 values with a nonzero previous balance (if it exists).

Comment: The solution here is to not use `itertuples`.

Comment: @cs95 What do you suggest I use otherwise? Or can you provide any other insight into why you think my code is not working?

Comment: Start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758), perhaps you can figure out a way to vectorise your code. There are a lot of useful links in my answer.